# How can I retrieve data from the controller and process it using jQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, autocomplete

I'm using this: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete
I want to suggestions as the user writes something from my input element with ID `tags`.

My controller:

```
public function addProducts(Request $request)
{
    $word = $request->input('name');
    $data = itemsNames::select('i_name')->where('i_name', 'like', '%' . $word . '%')->get();
    return view('admin.settings.products.addProduct', compact('data'));
}
```

My view

```
<div class="form-group col-4 labelform">
    <label> name *</label>
    <div class="controlsopop">
        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="tags" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = $data;
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});
```

I want your help to find out what the wrong point I fell in and thank you

Comment: You can use    
const availableTags = {!! json_encode($data->toArray(), JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};

Answer (score 0):

You can use your route as `serviceUrl`:

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: "{{ route('your_route') }}",
    preserveInput: true,
    autoSelectFirst: false,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        console.log(suggestion);
        // your operation
    }
});
```

And your route method in the controller:

```
public function addProducts(Request $request)
{
    $word = $request->input('name');
    $data = itemsNames::select('i_name')
                ->where('i_name', 'like', '%' . $word . '%')->get()->toArray();
    return response()->json([
        'suggestions' => $data,
    ]);
}
```